# Improve Magento2's speed in Vagrant

Tags: magento2, vagrant

I have setup the enviroment for Magento 2 development in clean Ubuntu 14.04 image. Installed Magento with no troubles, but I'm thinking if there is any way to configure Vagrant to improve page load speeds during development.

in my `Vagrantfile`, I've setup the synced_folders to my "global" coding directory. This way ALL magento files are synced via NFS.

`config.vm.synced_folder "~/Code/", "/var/www",  type: "nfs"`

Should I sync only `app\code` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your two .htaccess files located at:
`.htaccess`
`pub/.htaccess`

Go to the lines that contain `php_value memory_limit 256M` and increase them. In each of the htaccess files, this line exists twice, so that means you need to change a total of 4 lines.

I increased mine to 1024M and it made a huge difference. Of course, you will also want to check the memory_limit value in php.ini as well. Most likely, that file is located at `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` but you can run this command in your terminal to find the correct one. `sudo find / -name 'php.ini'`. Adjust the php.ini value if necessary and then reload with `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: Nice, so I would not need to sync only the folder that i am working on? `app\code`? If I change these parameters I can keep syncing the whole magento project? Thanks!

Comment: I am running multiple M2 sites on one vagrant box, all are synched. no problems

Comment: i should mention that it was VERY slow for me at first until i decided to track down the memory limits and adjust. Part of it also depends on the processor/memory on your physical machine as well

Comment: I work with a Macbook Pro late 2012 - i5 - 8GB

Comment: cool, that should be good. im on macbook pro 2014, so you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I made this vagrant which allow you to customize mount options:

- nfs mount or regular mount
- directory mount `/var/www/magento/app` or whole project `/var/www/magento`

You can work on a fast magento installation and adapt parameters depending on your work practice and your host machine perf.

https://github.com/zepgram/magento2-fast-vm